# How do you replace empty values with strings in an array (python)?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I want to enter the names of players into my array. I set the array to be empty, now how would I put the names given by the user into the array?

1.Here's my coding so far:

```
def randName(team_names):
    team_names = list(team_names)
    shuffle(team_names)
    leftover = team_names.pop() if len(team_names) % 2 else None
    trick = [iter(team_names)] * 2
    pairs = list(zip(*trick))
    return pairs, leftover

teamNames = []
name = ""

while name != "end":
    name = raw_input ("Enter the name of an opponent: (end to exit)")
    teamNames.append(name)

teamNames.pop()

chart = np.empty((len(teamNames)/2,2), dtype=np.str)

print chart
```

Comment: In what way(s) is this code not doing what you want, and how can you tell?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Isn't `teamNames.append(name)` doing what you just described?

Comment: Is this your whole code? Where is `pairs` defined?

Comment: btw: array is not list - list works different then array.

Comment: @drum I want to enter the names in the teamNames list into the array so that the pairs of players make it look something like a T-chart.

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, I forgot the line: pairs = list(zip(*trick)) before the return statement!

Comment: maybe you need `pairs = list(itertools.combinations(teamNames,2))` to get pairs - and then `chart = np.array(pairs)`

Answer (score 0):

In numpy you can alter a value of an array by referencing to the indexes of the element you want to alter, for example:

```
    chart[0,1] = 'Name'
```